# Assistance regarding tabs in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm currently working on a small side project as a way of getting used to Forms in Visual Studio 2012, as I usually only work with Console Applications. My current layout is designed to use tabs, and the user is to specify how many of the tabs they need for this application. They then fill out some information and it will be formatted and output to a file at a location specified by the user. On to the questions.

In order to stop duplicate tabs from existing, I'm using the following:

```
private void comboTabs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboSkills.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab8);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab7);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab6);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab5);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab4);
    }
    //repeat for Index 1, 2 and so on
}
```

There will always be a minimum of 3 tabs, so the first selection on the combo box removes tabs 4 through 8. The next selection does the same, but then adds tab4 back again. This goes on for the following selections. Is there any way I can do this more conveniently?

Second question, each tab has a series of text boxes and combo boxes that users are to select information from. The problem I'm having is that I need to identify how many tabs the user has selected and then only pull information from those tabs. I'm aware that I can get the number of tabs with:

```
int numberoftabs = tabControl1.TabCount;
```

But after that I can't seem to read the information from them. I'm intending to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberoftabs; i++)
{
    //get textbox text of tab i and so on            
}
```

Is there any way I can do this? I was hoping to use a tab layout since I like my current layout very much. If it makes a difference, all the tabs have the same layout, and share a naming convention such as tab 1 text box 1 is textTab1Name, tab 2 text box 2 is textTab2Name and so on.

Comment: Are you using Web forms, or WPF forms?

Comment: Just a small side note: If you want to keep up-to-date disregard Windows Forms: consider WPF or the new Metro Style

Comment: Some questions. Is there a reason for the 8 in your code or is it just a sample? Do you mean that when comboSkills.SelectedIndex == 1  you end up with tabs from 1 to 4, when it is 2 you have tabs from 1 to 5 and so on? Is there a reason for removing everything and then adding tab4 again instead of just removing tabs from 5 to 8?

Comment: regarding the second part of your question, what do you want to do? Are you just trying to get the controls contained in the tab, or do you want to set their names according to your convention, or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you can handle all cases with this piece of code:

```
var tabCount = 5 - comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

for (var i = 0; i < tabCount; i++)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(7-i);
}
```

For the second part you will have to create this method:

```
private T GetControl<T>(string name) where T : Control
{
   return (T) this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then you can write your text retrieval loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberoftabs; i++)  
{
    //get textbox text of tab i and so on            
    TextBox textBox1 = GetControl<TextBox>("textTab" + i + "Name");
    ...
    etc..
}
```

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" Unfortunately I'm a newly registered user. I'll be sure to come back and +1 once I'm able to :)